# How can I connect to NetworkManagers's dnsmasq instance via dbus?

Tags: networkmanager, d-bus, dnsmasq

I'd like to interact with the dnsmasq instance spawned by NetworkManager via it's dbus-Interface. I couldn't find the address, object path etc., the only thing I could dig up is: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/DBus-interface

I already tried

```
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.NetworkManager -o /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager -m org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq.GetVersion
```

but the method is unknown hence the method name is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out recently thanks to qdbus which helpfully lists all available paths and methods.

```
> sudo gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq \
     -o /uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq \
     -m org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq.GetVersion
('2.76',)
```